Return type based on optional object parameter
I have a helper function that takes an optional options parameter. Based on the options provided, the return type should be determined.
This is the current implementation without the deduced return type. It will always return type Promise<void>.
type Options = {
  awaitExecution?: boolean;
  returnResult?: boolean;
};

type MaybeAsyncFunction<T> = () => T | Promise<T>;

async function apiCall<ReturnType>(
  executionHandler: MaybeAsyncFunction<ReturnType>,
  options?: Options
) {
  const { awaitExecution = true, returnResult = true } = options ?? {};

  try {
    if (awaitExecution) {
      const result = await executionHandler();
      if (returnResult) {
        return result;
      }
    } else {
      executionHandler();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    /** error handling */
  }

  return;
}

The behavior I'm looking for is this: If nothing shall be returned, then the return type should be Promise<void>. If a return is expected, then the return type should be the return type of the executionHandler (Promise<ReturnType>).
The provided options (if any) in combination with the default values for the remaining options should serve to determine whether something should be returned or not.
const executionHandler = () => 'abc';

apiCall(executionHandler, errorHandler); // Should return Promise<string>
apiCall(executionHandler, errorHandler, { awaitExecution: true }) // Should return Promise<string>
apiCall(executionHandler, errorHandler, { awaitExecution: false }) // Should return Promise<void>

I am stuck and can't find out how to implement this. I have found a few similar questions (1, 2, 3), but couldn't quite work out the solution. My current solution still only returns Promise<void>.
type ApiCallReturnType<T, O> = O extends undefined
  ? T
  : O extends { awaitExecution: true; returnResult: true }
  ? T
  : void;

async function apiCall<ReturnType, Opts extends Options = object>(
  executionHandler: MaybeAsyncFunction<ReturnType>,
  options?: Opts
): Promise<ApiCallReturnType<ReturnType, Opts>> {
  /* try catch */

  return Promise.resolve() as ApiCallReturnType<ReturnType, Opts>; // To return void
}

Here is a Playground

If you want to use conditional types, maybe this approach meets your needs? Not sure about edge cases where some crazy person passes in {awaitExecution: Math.random()<0.5}. If you want to use overloads, maybe this approach meets your needs? Same deal with edge cases. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Yes, the conditional type solution is exactly what I was looking for.

I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

If you want to have a single generic call signature that uses a conditional type, you could write it this way:
type ApiResult<R, O extends Options> =
  O extends { awaitExecution?: true, returnResult?: true } ? R : void

declare function apiCall<R, O extends Options = {}>(
  executionHandler: MaybeAsyncFunction<R>,
  options?: O
): Promise<ApiResult<R, O>>;

Here ApiResult<R, O> checks the awaitExecution and returnResult properties of O, and evaluates to R if O can be assigned to {awaitExecution?: true, returnResult?: true} (so they are either true or undefined or missing); otherwise (if they are both false) it evaluates to void.  And note that the default type argument for O when you call ApiResult is {}, the type with no properties of Options set, so that leaving out the options argument is the same as calling with an empty options argument. Let's test it:
const a = apiCall(executionHandler);
//    ^? Promise<string> 
const b = apiCall(executionHandler, { awaitExecution: true })
//    ^? Promise<string> 
const c = apiCall(executionHandler, { awaitExecution: false })
//    ^? Promise<void> 

const d = apiCall(executionHandler, { awaitExecution: Math.random() < 0.5 }); 
//    ^? Promise<void> ❓

Looks good. Well, except that I don't know what you want to see if the property is some unknown boolean. You get Promise<void> here. Maybe you'd like to see Promise<string | void> instead?  You didn't ask about this use case, so I don't consider it in scope.  My point in showing it is that you need to think about edge cases and then either decide that you don't care about them, or modify the types so that they do what you want.

You could also overload the function instead, with two call signatures for the different possible output types:
declare function apiCall<R>(executionHandler: MaybeAsyncFunction<R>,
  options?: { awaitExecution?: true, returnResult?: true }
): Promise<R>;
declare function apiCall(executionHandler: MaybeAsyncFunction<any>,
  options: Options
): Promise<void>;

This is quite similar to the conditional type: if options is assignable to {awaitExecution?: true, returnResult?: true} | undefined then you get Promise<R>. Otherwise you get Promise<void> (and then we don't actually need the call signature to mention R). It behaves the same when you call it:
const a = apiCall(executionHandler);
//    ^? Promise<string> 
const b = apiCall(executionHandler, { awaitExecution: true })
//    ^? Promise<string> 
const c = apiCall(executionHandler, { awaitExecution: false })
//    ^? Promise<void> 

const d = apiCall(executionHandler, { awaitExecution: Math.random() < 0.5 }); 
//    ^? Promise<void> ❓

Playground link to code

Thank you very much! About the edge case: I don't set the values dynamically, so this is not an issue and I'm fine with it resolving to Promise<void>.
